# FATAL ERROR Only variables can be passed by reference on line: array_push(self::observers, array($event=>$call));

Tags: php

I don't understand why I get the error

```
class Observer
{
    static $observers = array();

    public static function addObserver($event, callable $call)
    {
        if(!is_callable($call))
        {
            throw Exception('param $call should be callable');
            return;
        }
        array_push(self::observers, array($event=>$call));
    }

    public static function event($event, &$param)
    {
        foreach(self::observers[$event] as $listener)
        {
            $listener($param);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `self::$observers` see that `$`?